# Apache Camel RedisIdempotentRepository Configuration

Tags: redis, apache-camel, consumer, idempotent

Has anyone been able to successfully get RedisIdempotentRepository working in a Camel Route?

My Camel Route is built using Java 8+, Apache Camel (2.17.1) and Spring Boot (1.3.3.RELEASE). The Camel Route loads and processes messages but does not filter out duplicates:

```
from("activemq:generic.order").
idempotentConsumer(header("uniqueId"), 
RedisIdempotentRepository.redisIdempotentRepository(redisTemplate,"camel-repo")).
to("activemq:unique.order");
```

The RedisTemplate is connected to a local Redis Server(3.0.4) and is injected with a Redis Connection Pool.

I tested the same Camel Route using the in-memory repository and the messages were filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

RedisIdempotentRepository was not the problem. My Redis instance was corrupted. The solution above works :)