# How to use ElastiCache as Camel Idempotent Repository?

Tags: java, redis, apache-camel, jedis, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to use [RedisIdempotentRepository](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.14.0/camel-spring-redis/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/redis/processor/idempotent/RedisIdempotentRepository.html) as [Idempotent Consumer](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html) for the camel Route. I tried with local Redis docker container and its working as expected with the following code.

```
IdempotentRepository redisIdempotentRepository = new RedisIdempotentRepository("redis");
from(source)
    .idempotentConsumer(simple("${in.header.CamelFileName}"), redisIdempotentRepository)
    .log("Uploading file ${file:name} started...")
    .to(destination)
    .log("Uploading file ${file:name} completed...");
```

Without providing any details, it is connecting to `localhost:6379`. How can i provide the `ElastiCache` details to connect for?

I tried these configurations ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389873/apache-camel-redisidempotentrepository-configuration), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681528/spring-redis-cant-connect-to-remote-host)) to build RedisTemplate and it is not able to connect.

Comment: You would need to tell more details about what error or what you see with - not able to connect. And check the unit tests of camel-spring-redis that can have some tests that can show you how to do it: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-spring-redis

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen, It was a issue with AWS security groups. I dont have a clue earlier that a node was associated to a existing secuirty group. I thought it can be accessible across the VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now. I have added `6379` port in inbound rules for the redis node associated security group.

```
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName("<cluster-name>.mdbnso.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com");
jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

RedisTemplate redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate();
redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

IdempotentRepository redisIdempotentRepository = new RedisIdempotentRepository(redisTemplate, "redis");

from(source)
    .idempotentConsumer(simple("${in.header.CamelFileName}"), redisIdempotentRepository)
    .log("Uploading file ${file:name} started...")
    .to(destination)
    .log("Uploading file ${file:name} completed...");
```